# Creating a list in Python by splitting indexes of another list possible?

Tags: python, list

I tried this following code but it has not worked so far it says that I cannot

```
names = ['John Johnson Doe', 'Jane Janis Doe']
firstnames = []

for name in names:
     firstnames.append(names[name].split(' ')[0])
print(firstnames)
```

The error I am getting here is:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: can you add the output that you're expecting please

Comment: Link to [Accessing and Working with Python Lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `name` contains the content of the list `names`, not the indices. So in the first iteration `name = 'John Johnson Doe'` and you are trying to use it as an index for `names`, i.e. you're doing `names['John Johnson Doe']`.

Just do the split on `name` instead of `names[name]` and all will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `firstnames` directly

```py
names = ['John Johnson Doe', 'Jane Janis Doe']
```

Then

```py
firstnames = [n.split(' ')[0] for n in names]

firstnames
['John', 'Jane']
```

Answer (score 2):

> The error I am getting here is TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) exception thrown by python interpreter cleary says that you were trying to use a `str` object as an index in your list. It means variable `name` is a `str` in your program. I think you were assuming it to be an `int`.

The Python for statement iterates over the members of a sequence in order, executing the block (code under for loop) each time.

Your loop variable `name` will be referning to one of the object in your list `names` in each of it's iteration. It doesn't hold an index to an object in the sequence.

I am assuming you want the first name of every string present in your list `names`. Here's how you should do it with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

```
print([n.split(' ')[0] for n in names])
```

However, I have rectified your code as well. Try this:

```
names = ['John Johnson Doe', 'Jane Janis Doe']
firstnames = []

for name in names:
     firstnames.append(name.split(' ')[0])
print(firstnames)
```

Outputs:

```
['John', 'Jane']
```

If you still want the `indexes`, then you can have a look at [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), try this:

```
names = ['John Johnson Doe', 'Jane Janis Doe']
firstnames = []

for ndx,name in enumerate(names):
     firstnames.append(names[ndx].split(' ')[0])
print(firstnames)
```